# How do I search a string for an ASCII character in Jython?

Tags: java, python, jython, uniobjects

I am pulling data from a database that uses the ASCII character 254 as the delimiter. I'm stumped as to how to search the string returned for the 254 and then create dictionary based on that?

My python class

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\IBM\\UniDK\\uojsdk\\lib\\asjava.jar')
import os.path

from asjava.uniclientlibs import UniDynArray, UniDataSet
from asjava.uniobjects import UniSession, UniFile
from asjava.uniobjects import UniSubroutineException
from asjava.uniobjects.UniObjectsTokens import AT_FM

class u2py :

        def __init__ (self):
            self.conn = UniSession()

        def get_db(self):
            """ establish a connection to Unidata """
            username = 'dbuser'
            password = 'SuperSecretPassword'
            return  self.conn.connect("host", username, password, "ACCOUNT")

        def close_db(self):
            """ drop connection to Unidata """
            if self.conn.isActive():
                self.conn.disconnect()

        def open_file(self,file_name,rec):
            """ open a U2 file read a record and return it """
            uvfile = self.conn.open(file_name)
            uvrec = uvfile.read(rec)
            dataset = uvrec
            uvfile.close()
            return dataset

        def open_field(self,file_name,rec,field):
                    """ open a U2 file read a record and return it """
                    uvfile = self.conn.open(file_name)
                    uvrec = uvfile.readField(rec,field)
                    dataset = uvrec
                    uvfile.close()
                    return dataset
```

Here is my code in the console:

```
from u2py import *

u2 = u2py()
c = u2.get_db() #creates the connection to the DB
c #actually makes the connection
rec = u2.open_file('SOFILE','SO133700')
print rec
```

Which then prints this to the screen:

```
ZZZAA■XN3■CEL■931819501■20020215■BWI/PP■■
```

"■" is actually a field mark chr(254)

EDIT:

When I use this:

```
    >>>rec = u2.open_file('SOFILE','SO133699').split(chr(254))
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'asjava.uniclientlibs.UniString' object has no attribute 'split'
```

EDIT and FINAL answer:

Using UniObjects Java

```
rec.toString().split(chr(254))
```

SUCCESS!!!!

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at `split()` .. this will generate a list. Not sure what you want to use as key/value pairs though.

Comment: There is no ASCII character 254.

Comment: something like `str.split(chr(254))`

Comment: Ok I'm a little slow but I see that rec is of the UniString type which has no split() method.  Hitting my UniVerse documentation now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`your_string.split(chr(254))`, e.g.

```
>>> "foo\xFEbar\xFEbaz".split(chr(254))
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

This returns a list. How to build a dictionary from this I'll leave to you, since I don't know what you want for keys and values.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I am looking for. I was thinking I could iterate through the string based on the 254 value mark and build the key from the total number of value marks returned.

Comment: Now I have another problem but I think this one is a problem related to the Java library I am using.

Answer (score 0):

To search the string for the ASCII 254 character, you can do:

```
if '\xFE' in db_string:
    # 254 char was in the string
```

or, to find the position of the

```
delimiter_pos = db_string.find('\xFE')  # will be -1 if delimiter not found
```

You'll have to explain what you mean by "create dictionary based on that" in more detail, though. Do you mean a dictionary of column names and values? What's an example of the response string from the database?